# Symfony testing my command demands passing parameter to constructor. Why?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

Symfony 6
Doctrine 3
phpunit

My origin command is running as it should. Nothing special about it. Now I wanted to write a test case. But all I get is:

Running: `php bin/phpunit tests/Command/IsbnCleanupCommandTest.php`

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1. App\Tests\Command\IsbnCleanupCommandTest::testExecute
>    ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>    App\Command\IsbnCleanupCommand::__construct(), 0 passed in
>    /var/www/company/tests/Command/IsbnCleanupCommandTest.php on line 18
>    and exactly 3 expected

Why do I have to pass parameters to the constructor when testing? If I run the command, I don't have to.

**My command**

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Repository\TitelmetaRepository;
use App\Repository\IsbnRepository;

#[AsCommand(
    name: 'IsbnCleanup',
    description: 'Add a short description for your command',
)]
class IsbnCleanupCommand extends Command
{

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, TitelMetaRepository $titelMetaRepository, IsbnRepository $isbnRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->titelMetaRepository = $titelMetaRepository;
        $this->isbnRepository = $isbnRepository;
    }    

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->addArgument('arg1', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Argument description')
            ->addOption('option1', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Option description')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $arg1 = $input->getArgument('arg1');
        
        // set state value to NULL (=reset)
        
        $this->isbnRepository->resetStateValues();

/* … flawless code  … */

        $io->success('You have a new command! Now make it your own! Pass --help to see your options.');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**My test**

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Command;

use App\Command\IsbnCleanupCommand;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class IsbnCleanupCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testExecute()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->add(new IsbnCleanupCommand());

        $command = $application->find('app:IsbnCleanup');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute([
            // pass arguments to the helper
            // 'username' => 'John',
            // ...
        ]);

        // the output of the command in the console
        $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
        $this->assertStringContainsString('...', $output);

        // or use the tester to assert on the exit code
        // $this->assertSame(0, $commandTester->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to instantiate a class which requires 3 arguments (`EntityManagerInterface, TitelMetaRepository, IsbnRepository`), but you provide 0 `new IsbnCleanupCommand()`. Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#testing-commands. Depending on what you want to test, but you'll have to manually inject real services or mocked services.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#testing-commands) I was able to run the test after changing my code there was no hustle with the constructor anymore.

```
<?php

// tests/Command/CreateUserCommandTest.php
namespace App\Tests\Command;

use App\Command\IsbnCleanupCommand;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class IsbnCleanupCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testExecute()
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $application = new Application($kernel);

        $command = $application->find('IsbnCleanup');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute([
            // pass arguments to the helper
            //'username' => 'Wouter',

            // prefix the key with two dashes when passing options,
            // e.g: '--some-option' => 'option_value',
            // use brackets for testing array value,
            // e.g: '--some-option' => ['option_value'],
        ]);

        $commandTester->assertCommandIsSuccessful();

        // the output of the command in the console
        $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
        $this->assertStringContainsString('Username: Wouter', $output);

        // ...
    }
}
```